# use tail in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

i have my file f1 contains x1, x2, x3, x4 each one in new line as shown in the figure below.
i want to read a given parameter n. 
if n = i, I want write the lines of f1 in a file f2 from position i.

Example if n=2 f2 will contains x2, x3, x4.

if n=3 then f2 will contains x3, x4.

My code below doesn't work perfectly. Does anyone know how to fix in using only the **tail command**

code:

```
t = $n-1
tail -n -$t  $F1 >> F2.txt
```

[image: F1_content]

Comment: Why can you use only `tail` command? Is it homework? This is a trivial job for `sed`.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code or samples. Write them.

Comment: `t = $n-1` tries to run a command `t` with arguments `=` and `$n-1`. The correct `bash` code would be `t=$((n-1))` to make `t` a value one less than `n`.

Comment: @Quasímodo i know but im asked to do it with tail. thank you

Comment: @chepner either with changing with you t=$((n-1)) im still having problem with the outputs. my file F2 contains only the last row of F1.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right option `n | --lines`.

From the tail [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

> -n, --lines=[+]NUM
>                 output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n
>                 +NUM to output starting with line NUM

So, based on this you should provide the option with a valid value that starts with a `+`, e.g.:

```sh
n=3
t=$((n-1)) # arithmetic calc -> 2
tail --lines=+$t $F1 >> F2.txt
```

Output of `tail --lines=+$t $F1` would be e.g.:

```sh
x2
x3
x4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but im gotting this error **tail: illegal option -- -
usage: tail [-F | -f | -r] [-q] [-b # | -c # | -n #] [file ...]**

Comment: @charles thank you for your feedback. Normally I don't post something before I test it unless I am 100% sure. Maybe it is distribution/version dependent, why it didn't work for you. Could you try `tail -n +$t` instead of `tail --lines=+$t`?